# Laravel 5: Event class namespacing / class not found

Tags: php, events, laravel, namespaces

This is more of a PHP namespace question than a Laravel question. I'm creating my first event and handler in Laravel.  I was following the manual pretty closely, along with [this nice blog post](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-events-and-handlers).

My EventServiceProvider.php script includes:

```
/**
 * The event handler mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'event.name' => [
        'EventListener'
    ],
    'App\Events\LeadSignup' => [
        'App\Handlers\Events\SendLeadNotification',
    ],  
];
```

I'm not sure if this is correct, but it appears to be working.  I've created the /app/Handlers/Events/SendLeadNotification.php file, which contains:

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Events\LeadSignup;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;

class SendLeadNotification {

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  LeadSignup  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(LeadSignup $event)
    {
        print("handling it");
        print_r($event);
        exit(0);
    }

}
```

Also, my /app/Events/LeadSignup.php event code is:

```
<?php namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class LeadSignup extends Event {

    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

My event firing code *was*:

```
\Event::fire(new LeadSignup($lead));
```

But this resulted in an error:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Site\LeadSignup not found

I was able to fix it, finally, by being explicit about the location of the LeadSignup class:

```
\Event::fire(new \App\Events\LeadSignup($lead));
```

My question is: How can I make the code more beautiful, like in the Laravel documentation, where I can simply call:

```
\Event::fire(new LeadSignup($lead));
```

?  Or, to ask another way, how can I add the LeadSignup class to my global namespace?  (My apologies iff I got the terminology wrong.)

## Solved!

lpeharda's answer worked for me.  I am firing the event in my controller code:

```
\Event::fire(new LeadSignup($lead));
```

Once I added

```
use App\Events\LeadSignup
```

.. to my controller code, the class could be found.  Here's my complete controller code so that you can see it in action:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Site;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Events\LeadSignup; // <=== here's the additional code

class LeadsController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();      
    }

    public function postInsert()
    {
        if(! \Lead::where('email', '=', \Request::input('email'))->exists()) 
        {
           $lead = \Lead::create(\Request::all());
           \Event::fire(new LeadSignup($lead));
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file where you are calling

```
\Event::fire(new LeadSignup($lead));
```

you need to add/use *LeadSignup* event's namespace.

So for example in the top of that file just add

```
use App\Events\LeadSignup
```

just below opening PHP tag (and below eventual namespace declaration):

```
<?php
```

Hope this helps.

If not, please tell me from where are you calling the

```
Event::fire()
```

facade and I can pinpoint the exact location.

Comment: Royal Bg, I hear what you are saying.  I think that lpeharda was referring to the top of my controller file, where my \Event::fire(..) code was.  Once I added the 'use' statement that he suggested, it worked perfectly.  Thanks everyone!